# How come CLI mvn deploy-file fails, but CLI mvn deploy with pom.xml file passes

Tags: maven, maven-3

When I do a "mvn deploy:deploy-file" with all the correct parameters, I get a "Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized", like it's not honoring my ~/.m2/settings.xml file. I know the file is good since if I do a "mvn deploy" which uses my pom file, it deploys the file. I see this when I run "mvn deploy:deploy-file -X" so I know it's using the correct settings.xml.

```
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/local/maven/maven/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /Users/my_userid/.m2/settings.xml
```

Any idea why this is? This is Maven 3.3.9

Comment: Most probably because the `<repositoryId>` in your configuration is not read...? Most probably because it is under an custom execution not used during CLI invocation...? Hard to tell without seeing the relevant part of the POM.

Comment: @Tunaki Thanks, your answer was THE answer. I had the repository option wrong in my command line mvn deploy:deploy-file. Once I fixed it it passed.